# I keep getting host error while sending a mail through php

Tags: php, html, ajax, smtp, phpmailer

I have been trying to create a php mailing system for my web application using this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0zwgJrSHd4&t=1019s reference. But I dont know if there is an error in my code or mail.

I'm using windows 7, php 7, latest version of phpmailer and xampp v3.3.2

```
<?php
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;



require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

//SMTP Settings
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = "tls://smtp.gmail.com:587";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "primeglobalhr@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = 'Password';
$mail->Port = 587; //587
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; //tls

//Email Settings
$mail->isHTML( true);
$mail->setFrom("primeglobalhr@gmail.com","hrmanager");
$mail->addAddress(  "adharsh136209@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = ("hello wasup");
$mail->Body = ("ntg much dude");

if ($mail->send()) {
    $status = "success";
    $response = "Email is sent!";
}
else {
    $status = "failed";
    $response = "Something is wrong: <br><br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

exit(json_encode(array("status" => $status, "response" => $response)));
 ?>
```

I want to send the mail to "adharsh136209@gmail.com" from "primeglobalhr@gmail.com" .

I have also enabled less secure apps on my gmail account and enabled the open ssl extension in php.ini, but its not working for some reason I don't know why.

error:

> 2019-04-05 17:32:29 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
>   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>   {"status":"failed","response":"Something is wrong:
>
> SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"}

Comment: have you tried to change the other port ?

Comment: Why start with something as difficult as the gMail server? Start with an easier server, like the one of your ISP or one of your own mailservers. To send to Gmail you need to follow these rules: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en **Read everything!** (I know you're probably not going to send bulk mail, but this still applies to you)

Comment: Follow that link to the troubleshooting guide - that's why it's there. It will tell you that your ISP is probably blocking outbound SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->Host = "tls://smtp.gmail.com:587";
...
$mail->Port = 587; //587
```

Don't send the port twice...

Comment: Bro... you are a life saver.... Thank you soooooomuchhhhhhhh